# JPA where can I found some basic explanations

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa

There are many resources where you can found information. Most of them highlights only some aspects. If you want to see overall information you should read a book.

Intention of this question is provide you with some light-weight article, that nevertheless covers all basics that you need to get started.

Comment: I don't think that "light-weight articles" are really the way to go if you are serious about learning JPA ;-) I'd recommend the book "Java Persistence with Hibernate", latest available edition, quite Hibernate oriented but a good start for JPA in general too.

Comment: My reference book is "Pro JPA 2: Mastering the Java™
Persistence API" This is pretty good book. The only problem is that it is pretty long, and basics are not well explained. Anyway, I post this question for my team members. :-)

Comment: Java EE 6 tutorial, part 6 : Persistence.
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbpy.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Understanding JPA, Part 1: The object-oriented paradigm of data persistence

http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-01-2008/jw-01-jpa1.html

Understanding JPA, Part 2: Relationships the JPA way

http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-01-2008/jw-01-jpa2.html